# Write a mysql query to get a publisher names who have not published book on Networking

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write a mysql query where we retrieve all publisher names who have never published a book on Networking.

Schema is:

```
publisher(pubisherid,publishername)

publishedby(bookdescid*,publisherid*,role)

subject(subjectid,subjecttype)

book(bookdescid,title,subtitle,edition,voltitle,volnumber,language,place,year,isbn,dewey,subjectid*)

writenby(bookdescid*,authorid*,role)

author(authorid,firstname,middlename,lastname)
```

Comment: You certainly must have tried something.

Comment: And you're asking us to do your homework why?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: To improve the Quality of your Question, please show sample data for `publisher`, `publishedby`, `subject` and `book`, as well as the output you would expect that sample data to produce.  Also, I recommend you either remove `writtenby` and `author` or better explain how they are related to the specific problem in hand.

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following where two (or more) `publisherid` values with the same `publishername` are still regarded as different publishers...

```
SELECT publisherid,
       publishername
FROM publisher
WHERE publisherid NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT publisherid
                           FROM publisher
                           JOIN publishedby ON publisher.publisherid = publishedby.publisherid
                           JOIN book ON book.bookdescid = publishedby.bookdescid
                           JOIN subject ON subject.subjectid = book.subjectid
                           WHERE subject.subjecttype = 'Networking' );
```

This answer works by using the inner `SELECT` query to choose a list of each `publisherid` (no repeats) who *has* published a book on `Networking`.  The joins create a table where every book (and its subject) published by each publisher is listed.  The `WHERE` clause limits it to only those books on `Networking`.  Since there may be many such books from that publisher, many instances of their `publisherid` could be selected.  We can get just one instance for each Publisher by applying `DISTINCT` before `publisherid` in the initial part of the `SELECT` statement that forms this list.

The outer query compares the inner query's list against the `Publisher` table and returns all values of `publisherid` that are not present in the inner query's results, giving us a list of all publishers who *haven't* published a book on `Networking`.

Please try the following where one publisher can have more than one `publisherid` value (but only one `publishername` value, which is not shared with other publishers)...

```
SELECT DISTINCT publishername
FROM publisher
WHERE publishername NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT publishername
                             FROM publisher
                             JOIN publishedby ON publisher.publisherid = publishedby.publisherid
                             JOIN book ON book.bookdescid = publishedby.bookdescid
                             JOIN subject ON subject.subjectid = book.subjectid
                             WHERE subject.subjecttype = 'Networking' );
```

The `id` field is usually considered the unique identifier for an entity, and tends to have a form that is more suitable for unique identifiers (i.e. is an `INT`, a short string, etc.), other fields can serve as the unique identifier for an entity.  I have modified my first statement so that `publishername` serves as the unique identifier for an individual publisher.

`publisherid` has been removed from the list of fields to be selected as you have only asked for a list of publisher names with no apparent need to add fields that will shed further information on that publisher.

The field for the `WHERE` / `NOT IN` comparison has also been changed to `publishername`.  This will eliminate records with `publisherid` / `publishername` combinations that have *no* `Networking` books associated with them if that `publishername` is associated with a `Networking` book elsewhere, as well as combinations that *do* have a `Networking` book associated with them.

`DISTINCT` needs to be added to the selection of `publishername` at the beginning of this statement, as otherwise publishers with multiple `publisherid` values will be listed more than once.  The same effect can also be achieved by removing `DISTINCT` and adding `ORDER BY publishername` to the end of the statement (but just before the `;`).

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: I am getting extra 10 rows in this?

Comment: If you are getting 10 extra rows and are asking why, it would help if you were to describe them - are they repeated values or does something else stand out about them?  I can try to create my own sample data set and try to test my statement against that, but in the absence of any knowledge about the data you are using I can not guarantee that  I will be able to replicate the problem that you are having.  As per my Comment to your Question, if you can provide a sample dataset that illustrates this problem, then I (and the others) will be better able to test our code.

Comment: Do you have different values of `publisherid` with the same value for `publishername`?

Comment: yes I have different values of publisherid with the same value for publishername

Comment: Where two (or more) `publisherid` values share a corresponding `publishername`, should we regard them as different publishers or should they be regarded as the same publisher?